# multiple definitions even though I'm using extern and include guards

Tags: c, makefile, global-variables, extern

Here's my header file.

```
#ifndef P6_H
#define P6_H



#include <stdio.h>
void FoundationC();      
void StructureC();       
void PlumbingC();        
void ElectricC();        
void HVACC();            
void SheatingC();        


extern int DAYS;          

#endif
```

I'm using a makefile to do all compilation. It's able compile the individual .o files file but when it tries turn those into a single executable it says that there multiple definitions of the variable DAYS even though that is extern and declared and initialized in each individually. I got this to work before but can't figure out why it's not working now. 
Oh and here's my makefile code

```
all:

    gcc -c P6.c
    gcc -c foundations.c
    gcc -c structure.c
    gcc -c plumbing.c
    gcc -c electric.c
    gcc -c hvac.c
    gcc -c sheating.c
    gcc  P6.h P6.o foundations.o structure.o plumbing.o electric.o hvac.o sheating.o -o P6
```

I realize P6.h probably doesn't have to be include in the command but the include guards should make it not matter no?

Also I'm sorry if this question is a dupe but I did previously look for answers and this issue is driving me crazy on a personal level despite the fact that's it's for school.

Here are the errors I get.

```
gcc -c P6.c
gcc -c foundations.c
gcc -c structure.c
gcc -c plumbing.c
gcc -c electric.c
gcc -c hvac.c
gcc -c sheating.c
gcc  P6.h P6.o foundations.o structure.o plumbing.o electric.o hvac.o sheating.o -o P6
structure.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `DAYS'
foundations.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
plumbing.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `DAYS'
foundations.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
electric.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `DAYS'
foundations.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
hvac.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `DAYS'
foundations.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
sheating.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `DAYS'
foundations.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: What you've shown here doesn't have any definition of the variable `DAYS`.  So it's quite hard to know what the problem is because you've not shown anything that could have caused it. And no, you should not compile P6.h. That's not how it works.

Comment: "...that is extern and declared and initialized in each individually". Struggling to understand your English, but does this mean that you define that variable in more than one .c file? If so, then that's the cause of the error.

Comment: Use prototype declarators, not the old K&R style. They are obsolete since >25 years now.

Comment: @Art If I didn't paste a definition then I'm clueless as to what it's complaining about I figured definition=declaration and/or initialization. I'll add the errors I get the main question.

Comment: @Olaf Idk what your referring to. As far as I know prototypes only refers to functions which I did in the header file

Comment: regarding this kind of line: `void SheatingC();`,  function prototypes, for functions that take no parameters, should have `(void)` not `()` because without the `void`, the compiler thinks any number of parameters, of any type, are allowed.   Which is probably not quite what your intending.

Comment: why is `P6.h` one of the files mentioned in the link step?  Header files only pertain to compile time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understand, the following is an extension of @FUZxxl's answer, which is correct. If you have the following in your compilation unit (a compilation unit is the .c source file plus all included .h files):

```
extern int DAYS;
...
int DAYS = 1;
```

then the second declaration of `DAYS` overrides the first declaration which stated it is an `extern`. So, the variable is now no longer an `extern` and if you do this in more than one source file you now consequently have multiple definitions and the linker complains.

If you must initialize `DAYS`, then you can do that in one place, preferably in the main file.

Comment: Thanks that worked I either forgot or didn't realize at all that when you initialize an extern variable in main that initialization is carried throughout the rest of the c files.

Answer (score 1):

> initialized in each individually.

There's your mistake. What do you think is supposed to happen if you initialize the same variable in different translation units? What do you think happens if these use different values?

You can only define a variable once in your program, multiple declarations are fine though. From all but one translation unit, remove the definition of `DAYS` to fix this problem.

Comment: What do you mean? I thought initializing the variable individually is how the extern works. I saw an answer on here to another question where someone said to either write the variable in the header like extern int var or int var telling the person who asked their question not to initialize in the header. It sounds like you're telling me to initialize the extern variable in the header but that causing a warning.

Comment: @codehelp4 No! I'm telling you to initialize the variable in one source file only. From your question it seems like you try to initialize the same variable in multiple source files.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,remove P6.h  from the last command in the makefile.-o option in gcc is used for compiling and linking multiple source files.So,this doesn't make any sense.

Secondly define DAYS as "int DAYS" in a .c file,you could declare it as extern in the corresponding .h file and include this .h file in all other source .c files.This will resolve this issue of multiple definitions.
Example:Define days as "int DAYS" in A.c and you declare it as "extern int DAYS" in A.h.Now,you could include this A.h in rest other source files like B.c , C.c ,D.c and so on.